# Flutter theme not being applied to checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a checkbox that is not accepting the theme data shown below:

```
      final acceptTerms = Checkbox(
        value: _acceptIsChecked,
        tristate: false,
        onChanged: (bool? acceptIsChecked) {
          setState(() {
            _acceptIsChecked = acceptIsChecked!;
          });
        },
      );
```

My theme for the checkbox inside MaterialApp:

```
 theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(Color(0xFFFF0000)),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    ),
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
        checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
        fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)
      )
    )
  ),
```

I'm expecting to see the checkbox fill color to be orange and the radius to be round vs square but it's defaulting to a blue fill color and staying square.

I am unable to figure out why. I can add the properties directly to the checkbox widget but I'd rather use a theme but currently it seems that isn't possible?

Full code from the register.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RegisterPage({Key, key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {


  TextStyle style =
     const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0);
    
    final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    bool _waiting = false;
    final _singleton = Singleton();
    bool _acceptIsChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.

    void showInSnackBar(BuildContext context, String value) {
      var sb = SnackBar(content: Text(value));
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(sb);
    }

    Widget okButton = MaterialButton(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: const Text("OK", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
      },
    );

    List<Widget> _buildPage(BuildContext context) {
      AlertDialog accountCreatedAlert = AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Success"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        contentTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        content: const Text("Account Created! Please login."),
        actions: [
          okButton,
        ],
      );


      final acceptTerms = Checkbox(
        value: _acceptIsChecked,
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        checkColor: Color(0xFF4C4184),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        tristate: false,
        onChanged: (bool? acceptIsChecked) {
          setState(() {
            _acceptIsChecked = acceptIsChecked!;
          });
        },
      );
  

      var page = SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/logo.svg",
                  width: 400,
                ),

                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: 2.0,
                      child: Theme(
                          data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),
                          child: acceptTerms
                      ),

                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    const Text("Accept Terms of Service?",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      var l = List<Widget>.empty(growable: true);
      l.add(page);

      if (_waiting) {
        var modal = Stack(
          children: const [
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.3,
              child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ],
        );
        l.add(modal);
      }

      return l;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Stack(children: _buildPage(context))
              ]
          )
      ),




        );

  }
}
```

Comment: your code works fine: tested on `Flutter 2.11.0-0.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b101bfe32f (3 weeks ago) • 2022-02-16 07:36:54 -0800
Engine • revision e355993572
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-69.2.beta) • DevTools 2.10.0-dev.1` - the only change i made was `shape: CircleBorder()` - most likely you added a `theme` but did not perform full "hot restart"

Comment: I did a "hot reload" however that did not resolve. I also rebuilt the project and that did not resolve. The issue persists. Not able to to 1.22.0-0-1.pre beta currently.

My current version:
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (8 days ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2

Comment: post the full minimal code then (something that can be copy / pasted and run easily)

Comment: I believe this comes down to environment and potentially how the checkbox is being constructed and used vs the example shown below.

Comment: so what does your full code look like?

Comment: I updated the above example with the full code, less the main.dart file which has the theme data shown above already.

Comment: `data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),` -> `data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),`

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, I've had to style the checkbox individually with checkColor, activeColor, shape and border radius and not use the theme for now.

Comment: you don't need it, all you have to do is to merge your top theme with local one with copyWith method

Comment: I had made changes prior and once I refactored and made the above change that resolved the problem. Bedankt!!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        ),
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
          checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)),
        ),
      ),
      home: const ShowCheckBox(),
    );
  }
}

class ShowCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowCheckBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowCheckBox> createState() => _ShowCheckBoxState();
}

class _ShowCheckBoxState extends State<ShowCheckBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 3,
          child: Checkbox(
            onChanged: (_) {},
            value: true,
            splashRadius: 50,
            tristate: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The same code is working for me -
**Upgrade your flutter sdk.**

Open terminal and run the following command:
**flutter upgrade**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQar.png)

Comment: I've updated the flutter version and received the following: Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (8 days ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
I think it's important to note that the way the Checkbox is being called in my example above differs from this example you have, and that may be the reason why the theme isn't working as it should.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        ),
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
          checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)),
        ),
      ),
      home: const ShowCheckBox(),
    );
  }
}

class ShowCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowCheckBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowCheckBox> createState() => _ShowCheckBoxState();
}

class _ShowCheckBoxState extends State<ShowCheckBox> {
  final Widget acceptTerms = Checkbox(
    onChanged: (_) {},
    value: true,
    splashRadius: 50,
    tristate: false,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 3,
          child: acceptTerms,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is almost similar like your code, then to its working properly.Do one thing copy my code, paste it in your machine and then run it, that's only the solution I guess.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWeVj.png)